# I told my computer to allow geolocation to localhost, and I'm still getting null for both coordinnates. How can I address this?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have:

```
        ANCIENT_CLOCK.latitude = null;
        ANCIENT_CLOCK.longitude = null;
        ANCIENT_CLOCK.register_position = function(position)
            {
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            }
        if (Modernizr.geolocation)
            {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ANCIENT_CLOCK.register_position);
            }
```

I have a Chrome instance for which I have agreed to let localhost to use geospatial position, and there is nothing on the console except for debugging output I've called for in console.log(). However, ANCIENT_CLOCK.latitude and ANCIENT_CLOCK.longitude are both null.

What can I do to get (non-null) coordinates for a user who has opted in?

Comment: Where did you put the `console.log()` calls?  They would need to be **inside** the "register_position" callback.

Answer (score 1):

That code [appears to work fine](http://jsbin.com/acitag/1/edit), but you don't show us the code that discovers the values are null.

Odds are in favour of you examining the values before the `register_position` callback has been called (e.g. by having `console.log(ANCIENT_CLOCK)` immediately after the call to `navigator.geolocation`).

Move your logic that depends on the geolocation data into that callback.